# Joomla 3.2 working with css files

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.2

I am testing Joomla 3.2 and trying to customize css files off custom and default templates but I can't get any changes to actualy display online.

First of all I thought it was a cache problem although it usualy is disabled on installation. I enabled and disabled it, cleared cache several times...

Tried several browsers clearing and disabling cache each time but still, my changes don't apear...

The wierdest thing is that I don't have that problem on joomla 3.1 and changes I make to index.php files apear.
If you have had that problem or have an idea where it comes from I would be greatfull for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out what the pb was...

My hosting service (a french company : OVH) is caching static files and I have to ask them to stop it while I am working on the css. Sorry for bothering, it is not a joomla problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the default template of your site and then go to:

```
root_of_your_site/templates/default_template_named_folder/index.php
```

and try to edit here, this will work.

Comment: Thanks for answering but as I said in my question, when I edit the index.php file, changes apear it is when I edit the file template.css that I have problems.

Comment: Is your template.css is loading on pages of your site?

You can check it using firebug(in css section) or any other developer tool.

you can also check console of firebug, it will tell you about errors and warning like script/css/image not found, etc.

Comment: When you say edit, are you adding new or changing .. you should really just edit the LESS file and recompile. Also you firebug/developer tools to see what is in the actual css file you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. spent hours trying to work it out. i solved it in the end.am sure someone else may do the same. i had checked JOOMLA cache was off, and my cache was cleared.

In my situation i had forgotten i have set to domain up to use a CDN (cloudflare) This was caching the CSS files. so maybe check this and tick it off the list just in case.

hope it helps someone