# CSS changes are not reflected in Joomla website

Tags: html, css, joomla3.0

I have a site built around Joomla, It was working fine from the time it was built. But from few days back the css changes in any of the css files are not reflecting in the site. I am able to see all the other UI changes except CSS. I have cleared he cache and checked from different ISP but no result. Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to force refresh your browser ...
http://www.wikihow.com/Force-Refresh-in-Your-Internet-Browser

Comment: Please check if your template has caching or css compression enabled. Please try also to clear your joomla and browser cache.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Mousa and emmanuel! I tried these options but no result. Can you please suggest me any other ideas.

Comment: make sure you use the right .css file. I know joomla has a lot, also I remember something like an `override.css` file, in which you can override css from another file.

Comment: Thanks Goosebumbs! you may be right but I do not have this kind of file in my template.

Comment: Hi guys, did anyone experience this sort of problem before?

Comment: I experienced this once and it was my HOsting service that was caching my css files related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192908/joomla-3-2-working-with-css-files you can try changing the name of the css file (also in index.php of your template)

Comment: if you're using chrome, pressing `Ctrl + Shift+ R` did it for me - as others have said, chrome/etc may cache old versions of the css and hence not update it automatically/view the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply but I found the answer. It is due to enabling CloudFlare in my hosting account. When I reached to my Hosting support they disabled the CloudFlare and everything started working fine and I am able to see all the CSS changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a Template which uses LESS instead of CSS. If so, see if there are any folder inside `"/public_html/templates/your_template/less/"` exists or not.

If it exists then you have to create (if it is already not there) a css file named "`custom.css`"

inside "`/public_html/templates/your_template/css/`" folder and write your CSS code inside this file.

Joomla will pickup this "`custom.css`" file at last and your changes will be reflected.